# Publish web content in a spring boot application

Tags: web, thymeleaf, spring-boot

Is there a way to publish the web-content in a spring boot application without restarting the whole application?

I use thymeleaf have tried to set the "spring.template.cache" property to false but with no luck

Comment: The `spring.template.cache` only applies to thymeleaf templates (clue in the name), and I'm going to assume it works because other people use it. Maybe the content you want to reload is not being loaded by thymeleaf? Or maybe you set up your own thymeleaf config and didn't use the defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `spring.template.cache` is enough if you run application with `mvn spring-boot:run`.

I am not sure about other IDE's, but in case of running application from Intellij IDEA in order to refresh Thymeleaf templates you need to **Make Project** (`Cmd+F9` on Mac) each time you want to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are building jar file, then first Change jar to war in build.gradle as fallows:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
War{
baseName= 'projectName'
version='0.1.0'
}
```

add the following statement in **dependencies**

```
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

add this class in your controller package.

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

It worked for me..